# adb push <directory>, but skip .svn .git (and friends)

Tags: android, push, adb

Is it possible to use `adb push` to transfer a directory, but skip `.svn`, `.git`, and other useless fodder during testing?

Below is what I have, but it wastes time, bandwidth, and storage:

```
$ adb push TestData /data/local/tmp/TestData
push: TestData/.svn/prop-base/xtrdh342.dat.svn-base -> /data/local/tmp/TestData/.svn/prop-base/xtrdh342.dat.svn-base
push: TestData/.svn/prop-base/xtrdh171.dat.svn-base -> /data/local/tmp/TestData/.svn/prop-base/xtrdh171.dat.svn-base
...
push: TestData/xtrdh342.dat -> /data/local/tmp/TestData/xtrdh342.dat
push: TestData/xtrdh171.dat -> /data/local/tmp/TestData/xtrdh171.dat
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe a bad idea:**

1. copy the whole folder
2. `cd` the copied folder
3. do push
4. delete this folder

Answer (score -1):

1. Back .svn directories up and delete them

   > $ find (LOCAL_DIR) -type d -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 tar --remove-files -czv -f backupt.tar.gz
2. Now you can push them happily

   > $ adb push (LOCAL_DIR) (REMOTE_DIR)
3. Restore local directory from the backup

   > $ tar -xzv -f backup.tar.gz